Cannot combine 2 translated/transformed images in Compositor
I am trying to combine 2 movie clips (actually the same clip which is transformed twice) which are overlays to my main scene. I want to use the same movie and scale them on the x-axis then mix them side by side and combine with my main scene using the mist pass as a factor for depth. Standard stuff.
However, I cannot figure out how to combine the 2 overlay clips. No matter what mix node I use, or work-arounds, blender only displays one of the transformed clips.
Here is the node set up:

NB...it doesn't matter that I have used just one clip as the source - you get the same result when it is duplicated along with the scale node.
Here are the precise steps to replicate:

Use an image as your main scene.
Find an image to use as an overlay
Use the scale and transform nodes to create 2 images from a single source, one for the left side of the screen and one for the right. The aim is to combine them - a way to get an overlay to look like it was shot from a greater distance and a slightly different angle.

Theoretically I should be able to combine them in a mix node, or an add node, but they do not work. I tried alpha over and I also tried to combine them with the main scene separately. I tried all the various modes for scale - absolute/scene size/render size, but it really needs to be "relative" in order to warp the aspect ratio the right way. I tried the transform node and every permutation I could think of, and that does not work either.
It's puzzling. I would have thought what I was trying to do was fairly straight forward compositing. I'm sure there is something I am not doing wrong, but I can't figure it out, and there does not appear to be anything on the internet that I can find that explains it.
